# Pandas group by moth only returns January

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simplified CSV file

```
Datum/Uhrzeit,Menge,EAN,Marketplace
01.02.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,15,Prod 1,A
01.02.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,22,Prod 1,A
01.03.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,27,Prod 3,A
01.03.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,27,Prod 3,A
01.03.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,26,Prod 2,A
01.03.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,20,Prod 1,A
01.03.2017 12:00:00 GMT+00:00,27,Prod 4,A
```

I would like to group the rows by month and calclate a sum of column "Menge" for each month:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=['Datum/Uhrzeit'], parse_dates=['Datum/Uhrzeit'])
print(df.index)
print(df.resample('M').agg({"Menge": "sum"}))
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).agg({"Menge": "sum"}))
```

However this returns

```
Datum/Uhrzeit              Menge     
2017-01-31 00:00:00+00:00    164
```

…instead of my monthly aggregation.

Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: Because there is only one month in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True` in `read_csv` and then,

```
>>> df.resample('M').agg({"Menge": "sum"})
                           Menge
Datum/Uhrzeit                   
2017-02-28 00:00:00+00:00     37
2017-03-31 00:00:00+00:00    127
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm feeling really stupid now :DHad two larger datasets… in one of them I guess Pandas inferred that days come first based on the data, in the other data set it did not.

Comment: Well, I guessed that. Glad to have helped. BTW, learning by mistakes is the best way to learn. @floriannorbertbepunkt